# Code a program with a nested for loop

Tags: java

```
public class numbers {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int num1 = 1;
    int num2 = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(num1 + "\t" + num2++);
        }
    }
}
```

output look likes this:

```
1     1
1     2
1     3
1     4
```

I need to use a nested for loop to get the output to look like this:

```
1  1
1  2
1  3
1  4
2  1
2  2
2  3
2  4
```

I'm stumped.

Comment: What is a nested `for` loop?

Comment: Here's a hint: you don't have a nested for loop in your code yet. Try adding one, then see if that helps. A nested for loop is a for loop within another for loop.

Comment: What if you tried printing out `i` in your loop instead of using `num1` and `num2`?

Comment: It's a loop ... within a loop ... loop-ception!!

Comment: @AntonH To be more specific, with _in_ a loop.

Comment: @hexafraction Yeah, I caught that .. good thing nobody noticed, eh? :D

Comment: @MikeB That would not be ideal...  it looks like he wants to ++ his num.  Just print I would not do that ;-)

Comment: @buzzsawddog You're telling me that using two nested `for` loops and printing out the loop counter variables in the inner loop won't meet his requirement of `I need to use a nested for loop to get the output to look like this`? I was trying to lead the OP in the correct direction without spoonfeeding him the answer. Alexey posted the full solution below, you can run it for yourself and see that it works just fine.

Comment: @MikeB no...   I am just saying that he had `num1` and `num2` that are present before the loop.  There is a potential that they mean something?  If he declares his two variables and uses the loop to inc an `i` and a `j` then his original vars never get increased ;-)

Comment: I think Occam's Razor would suggest that `num1` and `num1` were failed attempts at getting the required output. Did you read his requirement? `I need to use a nested for loop to get the output to look like this`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 2; ++i) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= 4; ++j) {
        System.out.println(i + "  " + j);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this too:

```
for(int num1 = 1, num2 = 1; 
      num1 < 3; 
      num1 += num2 == 4 ? 1 : 0, 
      num2 = num2 == 4 ? 1 : ++num2){
    System.out.println(num1 + "\t" + num2);
}
```

If you know the dance-steps (ABCDEFGH)

```
if(A,B;CG;E,F){
  D
}
H
```

Its easy to dance with (in mind).

Comment: This is way to complex for someone that cant even figure out a simple loop...  Its difficult to read, and not intuitive...

Comment: @buzzsawddog Its pretty easy if you know what order the executions go.

Comment: @PeterRader I get it, I understand whats going on.  But I do this for a living.  My point is...  An individual that can't even write a nested loop is not going to get it.  Its going to cause confusion and frustration.  I find it best to live by "Just because you can does not mean you should." AND Keep it simple...

Comment: I work with other developers.  I maintain their code they maintain mine.  Some work here and others don't.  Why go through the trouble to write something that looks like that when there are simple well understood solutions?   Any way, you write your way and I will write mine...

Comment: Hm, ok but your living better understand `for` once compleatly. The same for cascading/non-breaking switch-cases.